# smart app banners get hide with mobile safari address bar

Tags: mobile-safari

I know smart app banners is not a part of the document,so "window.scrollTo(0,1)" will got it hide too.
Is there any nice way to deal with this?

Comment: I haven't figured this one out yet too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and eventually tracked down a solution in the HTML5 Boilerplate mobile code.  The details area in my question, [Hiding address bar without hiding the smart app banner on iOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14047610/hiding-address-bar-without-hiding-the-smart-app-banner-on-ios-6/14169578).

Comment: Yeah,hide address bar after user scroll down is the only way.