# Hiding address bar without hiding the smart app banner on iOS 6

Tags: ios, web-applications, ios6

I'm currently hiding the address bar on iOS using the standard scrollTo technique (something like [this](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-web-apps/remove-address-bar/)).  I am also using an [iOS 6 smart app banner](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html), but when using the above technique to hide the address bar the smart app banner is also hidden up by the address bar off the top of the screen.

Is there any way to hide the address bar but not the smart banner?

Comment: The `scrollTo` technique relies on the fact that in mobile Safari, the address bar is hidden when the `scrollTo` function is called.  Since the smart banner is also rendered by the browser (it's not just a lump of embedded html), it may not be possible to trigger the two events separately.  My only suggestion would be to use `scrollTo(0, 0)`, although this won't work on Android devices.

Comment: Try using negative values in `scrollTo` (probably won't work). Otherwise look into using `scrollIntoView`. Try creating a empty element with JS and position it at `y=screenheight-bannerheight-toolbarheight` and apply scrollIntoView(false) on that element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story short, the clever folks at [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com) have already solved the problem in their [mobile version](http://html5boilerplate.com/mobile/).

Check out `MBP.hideUrlBarOnLoad` in [helper.js](https://github.com/h5bp/mobile-boilerplate/blob/master/js/helper.js), which hides the address bar and doesn't hide the smart app banner.  It appears that the key difference is probably `MBP.getScrollTop`, which gets a more intelligent scrolling point than simply scrolling to 1.

Comment: Even better would be to the [mobile version of html5 boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/mobile/); thanks for the reminder, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @ElYobo Do you have a working example of this?  I tried using the MBP code, but it did not work... the Smart Banner still gets hidden.

Comment: You can have a look at http://webapp.timetobond.com/, but there's really nothing to it, I just call the `MBP.hideUrlBarOnLoad()` function.  Note that you need to call it immediately, not in a jQuery ready handler (for example), because it needs to hook itself up to the load event.

Comment: @JasonTFeatheringham Did you find a way to get this working without hiding the Smart Banner? I'm also having the same problem that it STILL hides the Smart Banner.

Comment: @ElYobo This doesn't actually work. The Smart Banner still gets hidden. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry @ZachReed, last time I checked it was working for me and I don't have any iOS devices to test on.  Does [webapp.timetobond.com](http://webapp.timetobond.com) show an address bar for you?

Comment: Hmm, up again now; not sure who was messing with it, but I don't have access to that server any more.  Try again?

Comment: So, as far as I can tell, there is no way of hiding just the address bar with the Smart App banner showing. Hopefully in iOS 7.

Comment: If it's not working for you, I suggest that you [file a bug with H5BP](https://github.com/h5bp/mobile-boilerplate/issues); last time I had an iOS device handy, it was working well for me :)

Comment: HTML5 Boilerplate solution works very well. I took the gist of it, that's all I needed:

getScrollTop = function() {
            var win = window;
            var doc = document;

            return win.pageYOffset || doc.compatMode === 'CSS1Compat' && doc.documentElement.scrollTop || doc.body.scrollTop || 0;
        };

        window.scrollTop = getScrollTop();