# iOS Smart app banner with jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobile-safari

I am trying to use the iOS smart app banner on my website. I am currently using jquery mobile 1.3.1 for development. The problem I'm having is jquery mobile automatically hides the address bar on page load. Since the smart app banner appears to be a part of the address bar, the user cannot see the smart app banner unless they scroll up. Is there anyway around this problem? Ideally the page would load and show the smart app banner and not the address bar. However, at this point I would be fine showing both on page load. I know the folks over at HTML5 Boilerplate have solved this issue. See:

[Hiding address bar without hiding the smart app banner on iOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14047610/hiding-address-bar-without-hiding-the-smart-app-banner-on-ios-6/14169578)

The problem with this solution for me is turning off the hide address bar feature in jquery mobile. I can't seem to figure out how to accomplish without altering the jquery mobile core code. I don't really want to alter the jquery mobile code. Mainly because I don't like changing code that I have to update when a new version comes out. Plus I am pulling the jquery mobile file from jquery's CDN. I would like to find another way to solve this problem. Any ideas? Thank.

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
window.oldScroll = window.scrollTo;
window.scrollTo = function(){return false;};
```

before you load jquery mobile. This will override Jquery mobile hiding. then you can use the helper.js by reassigning scrollTo after jquery mobile script.