# Hide URL bar without hiding Smart App Banner on iOS

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, mobile, mobile-website

Is it possible to hide the address URL bar but not the Smart App Banner on iOS Safari?

I have tried the solutions from this question: [Hiding address bar without hiding the smart app banner on iOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14047610/hiding-address-bar-without-hiding-the-smart-app-banner-on-ios-6/14169578), but it doesn't seem to work. The Smart Banner still gets hidden when I use `MBP.hideUrlBarOnLoad` from https://github.com/h5bp/mobile-boilerplate/blob/master/js/helper.js, as the answer suggests to do.

Comment: Can you please provide some code? It seems that you need to call MBP.hideUrlBarOnLoad() immediately, not in a jQuery ready handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        mob.SetUpEvents();
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (jQuery("html.iphone").length > 0) {
                jQuery('html').css( "height", ( jQuery(window).height() + 60) + 'px');
                window.ScrollTo(0, 1);
            }
        }, 400);
    });
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: That still seems to skip the Smart Banner when I do that, though. :/ Do you have a link to a site you use it on so I can see if it works correctly on yours?

Comment: I edited the answer with the actual code. I use 400 ms of timeout to give enough time to have everything loaded. You can see it in [this website](http://www.volotea.com)

Answer (score 0):

The only reason this works is because it throws a javascript error on

mob.SetUpEvents();

Which makes it disable the scroll jump. It will however mess up additional javascript.

You can change it to anything which throws a javascript error and the banner will not hide.

This solution is not an effective one.

Thank You

The website volotea.com that you have linked to does not work, when the page loads it jumps and hides the smart app banner and the url bar both. We have to scroll up to see the smart-app-banner.