# Hiding Address Bar without hiding the smart app banner

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone, ipad

This question has been asked before twice but none of the answers worked for me.

[Hiding address bar without hiding the smart app banner on iOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14047610/hiding-address-bar-without-hiding-the-smart-app-banner-on-ios-6)

The above does nothing I put this in the jQuery.ready and in window.onload() but it does not scroll up to the smart-app-banner.

[Hide URL bar without hiding Smart App Banner on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18344178/hide-url-bar-without-hiding-smart-app-banner-on-ios)

This second one does work but throws a javascript error that mob is undefined.

This makes all other javascript not work.

Any working example would greatly help, any advice is greatly appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "mob" line. That line is used to initialize events of an object that probably you don't have.

Comment: I did try to do that, I commented out the mob.SetUpEvents() it does nothing then. It scrolls down when the smart-app-banner is loaded.

Comment: Also this condition is always false, is there something I am missing ? 
if (jQuery("html.iphone").length > 0) {

Comment: it's looking for a class "iphone" in the DOM. Do you have it? Can you paste your code?

Comment: as this is a company website i am unable to paste the entire code but there is no iPhone in my DOM, how do I add it ? Thank You

Comment: find the tag html and to the following:
    <html class="iphone">

Comment: okay i did that now it threw me an error that SrollTo is no such method, that was a typo i guess, i fixed that, now its back to normal it hides the smart app banner. It only worked when the mob was throwing a javascript error.